# AwesomeWM, Snapping in floating mode

Tags: awesome-wm

in the AwesomeWM, (on a fresh Arch install) I am looking for a way to snap windows to the left/right side of the screen in the floating mode. A bit like in say Cinnamon (Mint).

I am unable to do it, even after many attempts. I want to use something like Super+left arrow to snap a window to the left half of the screen etc.

The closest I found was https://gist.github.com/raidzero/dd7e45370b819eeff8aa#file-divvy-sh  but I am not understanding it. It says something like "o make this useful, use a key shortcut for each command :)" but I do not understand how/what to do.

Any ideas guys?

Also, I am not married to AwesomeWm. If there are any other (minimal) dynamic window managers where this is possible/easier, please let me know and I will switch.

Cheers.

P.S. that feature does exist when moving a window with the mouse, which is what is infuriating me so much... it should be easily done and I can not do it... at all...

also, I am rather a noob, so be a bit slow :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your question.  Please be aware that Stack Overflow questions should be regarding "specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."  I would recommend posting this over on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](https://superuser.com) instead.